# How to hide or mnimize a xamarin app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Does any one know how to hide or minimize a xamarin app ? I have an exit button on my app, i want to hide the app when the user clicks this exit button, just like Skype exit button.

In windows forms i use this command to hide an app :

```
 this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you told us what platform you were targeting - I presume you mean a Mac desktop app?

Comment: @Jason in visual studio for android app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Intent main = new Intent(Intent.ActionMain);
main.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryHome); 
StartActivity(main);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent main = new Intent(Intent.ActionMain);
main.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryHome);
main.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
StartActivity(main);
```